# ng2 input "Can't bind to <input> since it isn't a known native property"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass an input to a component as described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html):

```
<comp [str]="json"></comp>
```

This yields me an error:

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'str' since it isn't a known native property ("<comp [ERROR ->][str]="json"></comp>")
```

I also tried switching to the `<comp str="{{json}}"></comp>` notation... though the error remained.

I've tried to add the input both as:

```
@Component({
  inputs: ['str'],
})
```

as well as as:

```
export class Comp {
  @Input() str: string;
```

So far no configuration seemed to solve the error though...

What's up with that?

Comment: The component itself is created? Does it add its view to the DOM?

Comment: Did the test and it's what Günter assumed ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you didn't add `Comp` to the `providers` of the parent element. If the `<comp>` tag doesn't become a `Comp` Angular component, it doesn't have the `str` property.

Comment: Thanks again; I got it to work, though it seems I had to add it under `directives` rather than `providers` (using beta 0). I thought this might have changed at one point during the alpha. Is it still `providers` for you or was this a mistake?